# Return two separate columns of data from a function

Tags: php

Have just come across a problem where I believe this is the solution.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
function siteUsers()
{
    global $database;
    $q = "SELECT username, id FROM ".TBL_USERS."";
    return mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}

function generateUserArray() 
{
    $u = array();
    $i = array();
    $result = $this->siteUsers();
    while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $u[] = $row['username'];
        $i[] = $row['id'];
    }
    return $u, $i;
}
```

As you can see, when I then go onto use foreach, the `$u` and `$i` get split apart.
Is there anyway that I could keep them together?

```
foreach ($u as $username) {
    echo"<option value='$i'>$username</option>";
}
```

What I need it the option value to be the id and the visual value to be the username.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an associative array linking the ID to the username.  I'm assuming here the IDs are unique.

```
$users = array();
while( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $users[$row['id']] = $row['username'];
}
return $users;
```

Then:

```
foreach ($users as $id => $username)
{
    echo "<option value='$id'>$username</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($u as $idx => $username)
{ 
   echo"<option value='".$i[$idx]."'>$username</option>";
}
```

assuming equal length and that php function can return two values :\